# Is there a way to get gcc or clang to warn on a missing 'else'?

Tags: c++, gcc, syntax, clang, gcc-warning

I'd like to have the compiler warn me if I'm not handling every **if** statement's **else** condition.  Does this exist in either *clang* or *gcc*?

To clarify, I'm not trying to have this be on for *all* of my source code.  However, there are sometimes entire files or large swaths of code for which I simply cannot afford to not think hard about every single else block, by design.  So, I suppose, I'm really looking for a pragma I can turn on and off to enable and disable this for a few thousands of lines of very important code.

Imagine it as an automated code review, or static analysis tool.

To say that the compiler can't do it because it's legal is ... not a problem in practice.  Every C/C++ compiler I've ever seen will gladly emit plenty of warnings against code that is perfectly syntactically and semantically valid.  (For example in gcc, -Wunused-value, -Wunused-label, -Wunreachable-code, etc...)

Comment: Um, a healthy percentage of `if` statements don't *have* an `else` clause. By healthy percentage, I mean between 30% and 70%. Such a warning would be silly, leading to pointless code bloat (`else {}` at the end of every `if` clause) and noise.

Comment: I will add a clarifying remark to my question about my motivation.

Comment: Any `if` which contains `throw`, `break`, `return`, or `continue` has an implicit `else`: the rest of the code following the condition. Requiring an explicit `else` statement here would be a poor requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure how any of those keywords affect **else**, since the code in the **if** block running would mandate that the code in the **else** block does not, and vice versa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *really* want this, I might suggest downloading [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) and adding a check for this. Cppcheck does simple kinds of text-based matching to check against a rule set. It would be reasonably straightforward to warn for a missing `else` clause.

I implemented a prototype check for "missing else" in the `missing-else` branch here: https://github.com/ghewgill/cppcheck/tree/missing-else. This passes its own test but fails a lot of other tests because of the new unexpected style warning (on otherwise legitimate code).

Comment: That's a good idea, but yeah, I've written a C++ parser too... I'm really looking to not have to expand my toolkit, and my workflow.

Comment: @Will I guess in this case it would be the sane thing to do and in your make files you could specify for which files to check.

Comment: @WillBradley: There are many other benefits to running a static analyser like Cppcheck too.

Comment: This may be the only way to get what I want, but the cost of investing my own time in this tooling is not worth it to me, so in a sense, this isn't an acceptable answer.  It looks like the real answer is 'no.' :-(

Comment: @GregHewgill: Thanks for the recommendation to check out Cppcheck.  Very cool.

Comment: @WillBradley: I implemented a prototype check for "missing else" in the `missing-else` branch here: https://github.com/ghewgill/cppcheck/tree/missing-else . This passes its own test but fails a lot of other tests because of the new unexpected style warning (on otherwise legitimate code). Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks Greg!  Is there a way to use #pragmas to enable/disable this or other checks that CppCheck emits?

Comment: @WillBradley: There are ways to suppress specific warnings either on the command line, or with inline comments in the source code. There isn't a specific way to turn on or off warnings for particular sections of code, however, you can use a combination of `#ifdef` and cppcheck's `-D` option to isolate the code of interest (if it's just one function in a larger source file, for example).

Comment: So, I'm really curious how this worked out for you. Was my patched cppcheck able to identify your missing `else` clauses?

Answer (score 3):

A compiler simply cannot, a simple `if()` is a valid conditional statement.
Compilers warn for possible semantic mistakes, they are not meant to have/provide debugging facilities.
To get such functionalities you will have to rely on some code analysis tools which are specifically made for the purpose.

Comment: He's asking about a warning, not an error. Warnings are allowed for legal things, like not referencing variables and such. A compiler most certainly *can* warn on these things.

Comment: @NicolBolas: *Warnings are allowed for legal things* agreed. That is an additional facility provided by the compilers based on experience that users mostly err in using those. An `if`  without an `else` is hardly such an feature.The list could be endless if the compilers had to provide such features.

Comment: True, the list could be endless.  But, this one's not so ridiculous.  It's generally good practice to at least have an else block with a comment in it that says /* I thought about this, and it should fall through, or do nothing. */

Comment: @WillBradley: Who says that it's good practice? In most cases, it's obvious from the nature of the condition that it should fall through. A comment and an `else` clause simply take up space.

Comment: OK.  Sorry, you're right.  It's not always the best thing to do.  I'm merely asserting that _sometimes_ it's invaluable to force developers (including oneself) to consciously address **else** conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid a check like that would just bring up a mountain of warnings, since so much code doesn't use an else clause. But if you just want to check your code, you could use these little macros:

```
#define IF
#define THEN ?
#define ELSE :
```

Then you would just write your code like this:

```
int foo(bool flag)
{
    return IF(flag) THEN 0 ELSE -1;
}
```

Of course this is a bad idea.

Comment: guess what? they solve the porblem, as they gemerate an error if the ELSE branch is missing.

Comment: This doesn't get anywhere near general enough to replace `if`/`else`.

Comment: Yes, it would bring up a mountain of warnings, but I'd like that in this case.  As I mentioned in my revised question, I don't want this on across the board, just in certain translation units, or ideally in certain #pragma regions.